# Pinpoint SDK - How to track messages with SendMessages

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-pinpoint

I am using pinpoint SDK SendMessages using existing templates and substitutions. How can I track values like my custom message ID and other attributes using the event data stream?

It seems that Attributes are returned in the Kinesis stream if I send mail thru a campaign, but when directly sending message, attributes are not returned in the event data. Is there a way to set custom Attributes on SendMessages? I found no code samples on the web to solve this issue.